# In MJQ How can i remove hash from the URL?

Tags: jquery-mobile

i would like to remove the url's with hash to just the without hash urls, even while the click the new page links. as a exaple:

in case if i have the url like this:

http://localhost/mygame/#interface

then it should be like this :

http://localhost/mygame/

but, while click on the links, the page has to navigate. for that, i used the function like this :

```
$('a.play').bind('click',function(){ changePage("#interface", "flip", true, false);  });
```

but i am not get the required result, even i removed the '#' from the link. any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old version of jQuery Mobile. After 1.0 Beta 2 (I believe) they added support for removing the hashes from the URL. If you use a new version of jQuery Mobile this behavior will be enabled by default.

You can download the latest stable version of jQuery Mobile here: http://jquerymobile.com/download/