# how to remove the hashtag from the URL in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, hash

Just wondering:

I need to update the URL and remove all hashtag parameters before/after transitioning to a new Jquery mobile page.

Right now I'm trying like this, but it does not work:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page")', function(event, data){     

   var documentUrl = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( location.href );
   // update path and history
   $.mobile.path.set( documentUrl.hrefNoHash ); 

});
```

Is this possible at all? If so, how can I do it correctly?

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683862/in-mjq-how-can-i-remove-hash-from-the-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn hashing off when you try changing the page. Hope this code helps.

Example:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#About", {transition: "slide",reverse: true,changeHash: false});
```

Comment: good idea. I tried this, too. And it works, so you get the nod. In my setup however I'm "winding up" the window.history and hashtag with transitions which should not go towards the window.history. So after figuring out how to manage the hashtag, I was still stuck with my window.history entries. I eventually ended up unwinding the window.history by counting transitions and on pagehide I'm doing an unwind ala window.history.go(-myCounter). This also resets the hashtag so I'm a happy camper!

Comment: and it doesn't fire any Jquery Mobile transitions - if you unwind the correct amount :-)